# Background mode is not enabled in iOS tests

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

I'm writing a Swift library which in turn uses the AudioKit library as a dependency. When using AudioKit in iOS, you'll have to enable 'Background Mode' in the capabilities section in project settings. But when running iOS tests, there's no place for such configuration and as a result you're confronted with this error:

> CheckError Error: kMIDINotPermitted: Have you enabled the audio background mode > in your ios app?

I tried adding the corresponding "Required background modes" entry to the plist file for both the library and the test file to no avail. Perhaps the testing code for AudioKit can shed some light? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the AudioKitTestSuite project can shed some light? It runs unit tests on a lot of parts of AudioKit, but maybe not anything that requires MIDI. Here's the link: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/tree/master/AudioKit/iOS/AudioKitTestSuite

Comment: @AureliusProchazka yeah I'm doing that but can't seem to find any relevant code. AKTester isn't doing anything special... And the interesting part about the issue is that MIDI notes all play but the timbre is as bland as a sine wave.

Comment: It uses a sine wave when it can't find the source files.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka Thanks. That was a separate issue then. But I'm still getting the `kMIDINotPermitted` errors : (

Comment: After doing some research, I can't find a way to turn this on for a testing target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution:

Enable background audio in the "Capabilities" tab for your project, under "Background Modes."

[Reference](https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/48366658/audiokit++play+sound+files+at+specific+position+using+sequencer)